# Summary row on advanced query

Tags: mysql, sql

My schema looks like:

```sql
create table ads(
  ad_id int,
  ad_name varchar(10)
);

create table products(
    id int,
    name varchar(10)
);
create table ads_insight(
   id int,
   ad_id int,
   date date, 
   ad_clicks int
 );

create table products_insight(
    id int,
    product_id int, 
    sale int, 
    date date
);
create table ads_products(
    ad_id int,
    product_id int
);
                                    

                                    
insert into ads(ad_id, ad_name) values
  (1,'ad1'),
  (2,'ad2'),
  (3,'ad3');
 
 
insert into ads_insight(id, ad_id, date, ad_clicks) values
    (1, 1, '2021-04-25', 1),
    (3, 1, '2021-04-23', 2),
    (4, 1, '2021-04-22', 8),
    (5, 2, '2021-04-25', 6),
    (6, 2, '2021-03-03', 7);


insert into products(id, name) values
    (1,'prod1'),
    (2,'prod2'),
    (3,'prod3'),
    (4,'prod4'),
    (5,'prod5');
                                    
insert into ads_products (ad_id, product_id) values 
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (2, 4),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 1);
insert into products_insight(id, product_id, sale, date) values
    (1, 1, 10, '2021-04-25'),
    (2, 1, 13, '2021-04-24'),
    (3, 1, 15, '2021-04-23'),
    (4, 1, 14, '2021-04-22'),
    (5, 1, 17, '2021-04-21'),
    (6, 1, 15, '2021-04-20'),
    (7, 1, 13, '2021-04-19'),
    (8, 2, 15, '2021-04-25');
```

Here you have [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rEYvG9C8kRpKmhY7i3MhhS/3)

A quick explanation of schema:
I have ads:

1. each ad has insights, which tell us when a certain ad was active(=> ad_clicks has to be > 0).
2. each ad has products(many2many - `ads_products` table). Each product has `products_insight` which tells us how many sales that product generated on a certain day.

Now I want to get a summary row of this table:

```
| ad_name | clicks | product_sale | products          |
| ------- | ------ | ------------ | ----------------- |
| ad1     | 11     | 54           | prod1,prod2       |
| ad2     | 6      | 15           | prod2,prod3,prod4 |
```

This table represents all ads from the time range `2021-04-20` - `2021-04-25` which had `ad_clicks` > 0 AND count how many sales each ad has generated when it was active, which is done by this query:

```
SELECT 
    ads.ad_name, 
    IFNULL(ad_clicks, 0) AS clicks, 
    IFNULL(product_sale, 0) AS product_sale, 
    IFNULL(products, '') AS products
FROM ads
JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(ad_clicks) AS ad_clicks
    FROM ads_insight
    WHERE date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date 
      AND ad_clicks > 0
    GROUP BY ad_id
) AS ai ON ai.ad_id = ads.ad_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ap.ad_id, SUM(sale) AS product_sale
  FROM ads_products AS ap
  JOIN products_insight pi ON pi.product_id = ap.product_id
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ads_insight ai
    WHERE date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
      AND ad_clicks > 0 
      AND ai.ad_id = ap.ad_id AND ai.date = pi.date
  )
  GROUP BY ap.ad_id  
) AS pi ON pi.ad_id = ads.ad_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ap.ad_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.name) AS products
    FROM ads_products AS ap 
    JOIN products AS p ON ap.product_id = p.id
    GROUP BY ap.ad_id
) AS p ON ads.ad_id = p.ad_id
```

So the summary table should look like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+
| total_ads | total_clicks | distinct_total_product_sale | disctinct_all_products  |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+
|         2 |           17 |                          54 | prod1,prod2,prod3,prod4 |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT 
    count(*), 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT products),
    sum(clicks), 
    sum(product_sale)
FROM (
    SELECT 
    ads.ad_name, 
    IFNULL(ad_clicks, 0) AS clicks, 
    IFNULL(product_sale, 0) AS product_sale, 
    IFNULL(products, '') AS products
FROM ads
JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(ad_clicks) AS ad_clicks
    FROM ads_insight
    WHERE date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date 
      AND ad_clicks > 0
    GROUP BY ad_id
) AS ai ON ai.ad_id = ads.ad_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ap.ad_id, SUM(sale) AS product_sale
  FROM ads_products AS ap
  JOIN products_insight pi ON pi.product_id = ap.product_id
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ads_insight ai
    WHERE date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
      AND ad_clicks > 0 
      AND ai.ad_id = ap.ad_id AND ai.date = pi.date
  )
  GROUP BY ap.ad_id  
) AS pi ON pi.ad_id = ads.ad_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ap.ad_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.name) AS products
    FROM ads_products AS ap 
    JOIN products AS p ON ap.product_id = p.id
    GROUP BY ap.ad_id
) AS p ON ads.ad_id = p.ad_id) AS p;
```

But it is wrong because it is returning this:

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+
| total_ads | total_clicks | distinct_total_product_sale | disctinct_all_products  |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+
|         2 |           17 |                          69 | prod1,prod2,prod2,prod3,prod4 |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+
```

`disctinct_all_products` does not work, because there is duplicated `prod2`
And `distinct_total_product_sale` does not work because it should be 54, not 69.

54 because we only count sales when there is an ad_insight on a certain date. So for example there is a sale on `2021-04-24` for `prod1` but there is no insight, so we do not count this sale.

Comment: . . I fell like you are asking the same question every day.  Perhaps there is a way you can simplify the question and data so you can actually get it answered.  If the questions are actually different, you might want to highlight the differences.

Comment: This is the most simplified version, do you know the answer?

Comment: Your question is how to remove the duplicates from joining over a many to many relation with filters on both sides. You can simplify your example by removing two tables. That would make the listings much shorter.

Comment: which tables shoud I remove?

Comment: Does the solution have to be for MySQL version 5.7 as per the fiddle or could it use MySQL 8.0?

Comment: You can use 8.0

Comment: `) AS p ON ads.ad_id = p.ad_id) AS p;` -- Please don't reuse an alias (`p`).  It makes it hard for humans to read and may lead to the parser screwing up.

Comment: Ok, do you have an idea how to solve my problem?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually this:

On `'2021-04-25'`, two ad ids, 1 and 2, are active and both according to the `ads_products` table are relevant to `product_id` number 2, which had a sale of 15 for that day. So 15 is getting double-counted with your SQL.

Try the following (but perhaps you meant for the final column to be **distinct_all_product** rather than **disctinct_all_product**).

```
select sq1.*, sq2.*, sq3.* FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(distinct ad_id) AS total_ads, SUM(ad_clicks) AS ad_clicks FROM ads_insight
    WHERE date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date AND ad_clicks > 0
) sq1 join (
    SELECT SUM(sale) AS distinct_total_product_sale FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT pi.product_id, pi.sale, pi.date FROM ads_products AS ap
        JOIN products_insight pi ON pi.product_id = ap.product_id AND date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
        JOIN ads_insight ai on ap.ad_id = ai.ad_id AND pi.date = ai.date and ai.ad_clicks > 0
    ) sq
) sq2 join (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.name) AS disctinct_all_products
    FROM ads_insight AS ai JOIN ads_products AS ap
        ON ai.date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date AND ai.ad_clicks > 0 AND ai.ad_id = ap.ad_id
    JOIN products AS p ON ap.product_id = p.id
) sq3;
```

| total_ads | ad_clicks | distinct_total_product_sale | disctinct_all_products |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 17 | 54 | prod1,prod2,prod3,prod4 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ivn1sKwX77GYfQGdjGYeeP/0)

**UPDATE**

I've added below two query plans. The first one is with the tables as you defined them, i.e. with no keys defined for the tables (and thus no indexes) and the second query plan after I added a few keys (and thus indexes). You can see that the second query plan is now using indexes. So I don't know why you say that indexes are not important.

I believe I answered your original question. If you know more about optimization than I do, as you seem to be saying, you should be able to take it from here. Or else, you should open a second question, which is really now a question about optimization. Or you can do as I asked and publish your schema showing your indexes and I will take a look at that. I don't know what more I can do for you or what you think your 50 points entitles you to. But *we* don't *have to* do anything.

**Query Plan with no keys defined**

```
SET @from_date = '2021-04-20';
SET @to_date = '2021-04-25';

EXPLAIN
    SELECT SUM(sale) AS distinct_total_product_sale FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT pi.product_id, pi.sale, pi.date FROM ads_products AS ap
        JOIN products_insight pi ON pi.product_id = ap.product_id AND date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
        JOIN ads_insight ai on ap.ad_id = ai.ad_id AND pi.date = ai.date and ai.ad_clicks > 0
    ) sq
;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 2 | 100 |  |
| 2 | DERIVED | pi |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 8 | 12.5 | Using where; Using temporary |
| 2 | DERIVED | ai |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 5 | 20 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
| 2 | DERIVED | ap |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 6 | 16.67 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |

---

**Query Plan with some keys defined**

```
create table ads_insight(
   id int,
   ad_id int,
   date date, 
   ad_clicks int,
   primary key(id),
   unique key(ad_id, date, ad_clicks)
 );
create table products(
    id int,
    name varchar(10)
);
create table products_insight(
    id int,
    product_id int, 
    sale int, 
    date date,
    primary key(id),
    unique key(product_id, date)
);
create table ads_products(
    ad_id int,
    product_id int,
    primary key(ad_id, product_id)
);

SET @from_date = '2021-04-20';
SET @to_date = '2021-04-25';

EXPLAIN
    SELECT SUM(sale) AS distinct_total_product_sale FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT pi.product_id, pi.sale, pi.date FROM ads_products AS ap
        JOIN products_insight pi ON pi.product_id = ap.product_id AND date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
        JOIN ads_insight ai on ap.ad_id = ai.ad_id AND pi.date = ai.date and ai.ad_clicks > 0
    ) sq
;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 2 | 100 |  |
| 2 | DERIVED | pi |  | ALL | product_id |  |  |  | 8 | 12.5 | Using where; Using temporary |
| 2 | DERIVED | ai |  | index | ad_id | ad_id | 14 |  | 5 | 20 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
| 2 | DERIVED | ap |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | test.ai.ad_id,test.pi.product_id | 1 | 100 | Using index |

---

Comment: On big data set it is executing so slow, can we optimize it?

Comment: I am not a Big Data expert but it is generally a question what indexes you have set. Preface the SQL with `explain` to see what the Query Plan is. Was your (incorrect) SQL any faster?

Comment: The previous query(incorrect) was significantly faster.

Comment: We have to optimize the second join(`sq2`). It is taking 99% time of executing the whole query

Comment: That's the one that corrects the SQL. I have to go out for a while. When I return I will look at it. *You* need to get the query plan for that by executing that SQL with `explain` before it as in `explain SELECT SUM(sale) AS ...`. You need to update question with the query plan and show the actual schema showing what keys have been defined for the tables.

Comment: Can't wait for your correction. Indexes are not important here, you can skip them. We have to optimize/change second join.

Comment: But still it is slow, even after adding indexes